# Not all POST array elements getting sent

Tags: html, post

I have a table which has 4 columns with the first column containing a text input boxes.  The entire table is wrapped inside a form that will run a PHP script on that data.  As of right now, I'm just printing out the POST array.  The problem is that I'm missing some of the values that I write into the input fields.  So putting the values 1-10 in the first 10 text inputs gives me the following in print_r:

```
Array
(
[65710] =>
[65705] => 2
[269200318] => 
[269200586] => 4
[16830189] => 
[16829165] => 
[1051902] => 7
[65742] => 
[16830122] => 
[269339822] => 10
}
```

The HTML for this form can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/nY9MF/

This is running on IIS 7

Edit: I updated the jsfiddle code to have the full table for one of these stores.  This is the POST array after I hit submit:

```
Array(
[65710] => 
[65705] => 2
[269200318] => 
[269200586] => 4
[16830189] => 
[16829165] => 
[1051902] => 7
[65742] => 
[16830122] => 
[269339822] => 10
[65774] => 
[16821982] => 
[65740] => 
[16825517] => 
[65709] => 
[1051326] => 
[1052334] => 
[65773] => 
[4110] => 
[16837342] => 
[16825518] => 
[1051375] => 
[1051594] => 
[65743] => 
[1052108] => 
[256] => 
[4106] => 
[65711] => 
[65738] => 
[1051597] => 
[4109] => 
[65724] => 
[SaveQuantity] => Save
```

)

Comment: I copied the HTML you have provided, saved it on my PC and ran it. I am getting all the data from 1 to 10. One question, why have you named the text fields of `65710`, `65705` etc?

Comment: its the hex value of the identifying string for each row.